# Concatenate string node in loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I've the following code and its working if `result[1]` have length is 1 like following:

```
var url = redir[0] + 'value=' + encoURL + '& + result[1];
```

Now I have scenario when result have more entries 3 or five and I need to concatenate it to the string,there is nice way to do it instead of this ugly way

```
var url = redir[0] + 'value=' + encoURL + '& + result[1] + '& + result[2] + '& + result[3]
```

and etc.

I have use **lo-dash** and **underscore** ...

Comment: Both your strings are missing their terminating `'`, so I doubt either of them are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it looks as if you want all the results appended to the value, delimited by ampersands.  If that is what you want then this will do what you need...

```
// get a copy of result, with the first element removed...
var newResult = result.slice(1);
var url = redir[0] + 'value=' + encoURL + (newResult.length ? "&" : "") + newResult.join("&");
```

`join` will concatenate all the values of `newResult`, delimited by an ampersand.

`(newResult.length ? "&" : "")` basically adds the first ampersand if there are any values in `newResult`, so it handles the possibility that `newResult` is empty.  You could also put the join inside that conditional operator, but I did it like this as it's more readable, and it makes no difference to the end result.

I created `newResult` so you still have the original result array intact, in case you need it later.

Comment: Thanks 1+ but I need to start the result from entry 1 ...how can I adopt it ?

Comment: I've added something extra to handle that.